# serializeObject on form selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML form with a number of inputs, I wish to turn the elements of the form into a JSON string. So I have something like the following

```
$('#myForm').submit( function() {
    var data = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject());
    //do more stuff
});
```

I am however getting

> Object doesn't support property or method 'serializeObject'

Any ideas? I can see from the debugger that `this` is a `HTMLFormElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `.serializeArray()` which returns, like the [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) say:

> a JavaScript array of objects, ready to be encoded as a JSON string. It operates on a jQuery collection of forms and/or form controls.

You should update your code to the following:

```
$('#myForm').submit( function() {
    var data = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray());
    //do more stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is serialize() and serializeArray() but no serializeObject().
are you using any other library or what?